# extracting and pasting a part of string using javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, replace

I have people inputting
    125px and 125%
I want to extract just 125 from this perform some calulation on it.
    125 * 2
Then I want to add px or % as it was set before
    250px and 250%

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing something like this should work:

```
//str is equal to your string
var num = str.substring(0,str.search(/[^0-9]/))/1;
var sub = str.substring(str.search(/[^0-9]/));
num=num*2;
var newstr = num+sub;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Emile](https://github.com/madrobby/emile/blob/master/emile.js) uses `parseFloat` to get the number and `replace` to get rid of anything that isn't the unit:

```
function parse(prop){
    var p = parseFloat(prop),
        q = prop.replace(/^[\-\d\.]+/, '');

    ...
}
```

Then `p` is the number, and `q` is the unit.